# What access do I need in GCP/Firebase to run Firebase testlab

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-test-lab

I have a GCP project that I want add to add firebase to it and then give some QA users access to execute Firebase TestLab.

The group is already created in GCP .What access to do I need to give the group in GCP and Firebase to be able to run FireBase TestLab?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For read only access across the console you have to grant [firebase.viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles/details/roles%3Cfirebase.viewer) role.

For full view and edit access you have to grant [firebase.admin](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles/details/roles%3Cfirebase.admin) role.

Each of the Firebase * Admin roles provide admin access to a subset of the product, respective of the name:

```
Firebase Develop Admin/Viewer: maps to the products in the "Build" dropdown of the console
Firebase Grow Admin/Viewer: maps to the products in the "Engage" dropdown of the console
Firebase Quality Admin/Viewer: maps to the products in the "Release & Monitor" dropdown of the console
Firebase Analytics Admin/Viewer: maps to the products in the "Analytics" dropdown of the console
```